# Partitioning over 500+ filegroups on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have a database that includes partitioning table on daily basis and it has 500+ over datafiles for each day. Is this the best practice or it should be better if i make it into 10 filegroups ?

For example;

I have customer_order table and table has 100 million + rows and queries always includes order_date columns in where condition.

I want to partition o daily basis, however for 3 years it contains 1000+ filegroups ( datafiles ). 
Should i create 1000 filegroups/datafiles or just create 3 fg/df for each year?

Comment: can you explain with examples ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar edited, thank you.